# Approximation of distribution that has a positive atom by well-known parametric distributions

Tags: distributions, maximum-likelihood, mixture-distribution, nonparametric

I have a variable (say, $y$) in my dataset for which a lot of observations are clustered around some point $c$ and after the point $c$ the distribution looks continuous. I imagine that would be the case when the c.d.f. of $y$ has a jump discontinuity at $c$ and then is continuous after that.

What are the usual ways to approximate distributions like this using well known parametric distributions? I would like to do MLE after choosing a suitable parametric class.

Comment: In my answer I assume that clustered around c means you observe it as c. If not you have no way of knowing that it is a constant (atom).

Answer (score -1, accepted):

This is a mixture of two distributions $p_1 c + (1-p_1) f(x)$, where $f(x)$ is a density from the parametric family.

So for example $f(x)$ could be a normal density with mean $\mu$ and variance $\sigma^2$. You would estimate $p_1$ by the number of samples that equal $c$ and $\mu$ and $\sigma^2$ by the usual maximum likelihood estimates. I am assuming $c$ is known, but if not it will be the only value that repeats.

This is better expressed in terms of the cumulative normal distribution (or other parametric distribution).

Comment: Your formula for a mixture of distributions is incorrect.  This mixture does not have a density at all!  You can write a valid formula in terms of a generalized distribution (a "Dirac delta") or in terms of the CDFs or CFs.

Comment: @whuber I think you are saying that this is a matter of notation right? The estimation from the sample would go the way way I described it.

Comment: This is not a mere "matter of notation," because the standard interpretation of the mathematical formula you wrote yields something that is not a valid density.  It's not even clear that the ML estimation would proceed as you have described, because the question describes data that are "clustered around" $c$ rather than all being exactly equal to $c$.

Comment: My point is about the method of estimation.  I realize that formally the Dirac delta function is used to represent a discrete component.  Tell me how you would like me to represent the mixture distribution and I will change my answer appropriately. The OP says clustered around c but you can't distinguish that from a density that may have a peak at c.  This goes against his statement that "after the point c the distribution looks continuous.

Comment: Also other than editing the original post I have not heard a response from the OP about the matter.

Comment: Please note that your suggestion that $f$ could be Normal is inconsistent.  If that's the case, then there may be a substantial chance in this model of observing values *less* than $c$. You implicitly have assumed the support of $f$ *must* be on the interval $(c,\infty)$, ruling out Normal distributions.  At this juncture you might want to seek clarification from the OP concerning *why* values might be accumulating at $c$: perhaps, for instance, these are left-censored data. It does not look like you are really ready to be recommending any specific model or solution.

Comment: Good point! I see that the normal distribution would have to be 0 at c which of course is not possible.  I do think that nothing precludes the continuous part of the distribution being positive below c.  Still have no idea what kind of situation the OP is dealing with.  The choice of f was a continuous distribution from a parametric family.  I pick the normal for simplicity but technically an exact normal is not possible.

Comment: Thanks @whuber for comments. Just to clarify: variable $y$ can take only values greater or equal than $c$, an this is not due to censoring or truncation but due to the nature of the variable itself -- say, $c$ is the minimum wage but I observe lots of individuals with wages very close to the minimum wage but not quite there. So in a finite sample I have only very few observations exactly at $c$ and lots of observations in a small neighborhood of $c$. I imagine this could potentially be consistent with having an atom at $c$, or no atom but a lot of mass around $c$.

Comment: Thanks @MichaelChernick for comments. Just to clarify: variable $y$ can take only values greater or equal than $c$, an this is not due to censoring or truncation but due to the nature of the variable itself -- say, $c$ is the minimum wage but I observe lots of individuals with wages very close to the minimum wage but not quite there. So in a finite sample I have only very few observations exactly at $c$ and lots of observations in a small neighborhood of $c$. I imagine this could potentially be consistent with having an atom at $c$, or no atom but a lot of mass around $c$.

Comment: Alik, Sometimes it is fruitful to think of such variables with artificial bounds (like a minimum wage) as being "naturally" censored: there is a hypothetical unobservable "real wage" that is replaced by the minimum wage whenever it is less than the minimum.  Whether or not that is a good theory, it does show how and why your data are still amenable to analysis with censored-data methods.

Comment: @MichaelChernick Sorry, an accident. Will accept it again.

Comment: I think there are excellent reasons not to accept this answer, not least of which is that the mathematical expression in it is (still) wrong!

Comment: Maybe you should leave the alone.  The OP seems to understand the answer and the problem with the notation has been explained.

Comment: I am concerned that you might have misled the OP and be misleading many other readers who happen upon this thread.  Indeed, it appears from the comment thread that the reason the OP has accepted your answer is that you demanded it of him and he, as a newcomer, did not understand his options and therefore complied.  *At a minimum* you could fix your post so that the mathematical expressions in it make sense and are correct!